# JSON element reader .NET

Tags: c#, json, winforms, json.net

I have a simple JSON example like this :

```
{
   "items": {
      "element": ["item 1","item 2"]
   },
   "name": "James"
}
```

and a JSON Schema like this :

```
{
 'type': 'object',
 'properties': {
    'name': {'type':'string'},
    'items': {
        'type': 'object',
        'properties':{
            'element':{
                'type':'array',
                'items':[{'type':'string', 'type':'string'}]
             }
        }
    }
  },
 'additionalProperties': false
}
```

Calling `"IsValid()"` method in JSON.NET using the given Schema and Data will return `VALID`. 

Question : 
How do I traverse and edit the elements inside JSON ? 
My objective is to look-up values of node `"element"` in database and then replace it with a generalized value if they exists e.g `"item 1"` exists in database and will replaced with `"general value A"`. However, `"item 2"` doesn't exist in database and should throw some kind of error message when `IsValid()` method is called.

Note that this is a desktop application using .NET 4.5 and JSON.NET library, and it will be used as a data-cleansing tool. I'm open to any kind of alternative libraries as long as they are compatible with .NET 4.5 though..

Comment: I use Newtonsoft's JSON library. You can, for example, traverse using the JToken class methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not fully understand the part of your question with `IsValid()` issue, but if talk about traversing through json elements and editing, you can use 2 methods.
Install Newtonsoft.Json at first in Package-Manager in VS: `Install-package newtonsoft.json`.

1. Create class `JsonItems`, which describes your input JSON hierarchy

   ```
     class JsonItems
     {
        public Items items;
        public string name;
     }

     class Items
     {
        public List<string> elements { get; set; }
     }
   ```

Now you can legally deserialize your json and edit `result` as any .net object.

```
       string jsonItems = @"{
                        'items': {
                           'element': ['item 1','item 2']
                        },
                        'name': 'James'
                    }";

        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonItems>(jsonItems);

        result.items = new Items
        {
            elements = new List<string> {"itemd 3", "item 4"}
        };
```

2. The second way is more quick (in implementation), but less secuarble in runtime. With help of `dynamic`.

```
        dynamic d = JObject.Parse(jsonItems);
        d.items.element[1] = "item 3";
```